# How to open deep link from mobile browser?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, deep-linking

I have created a deep link for my app, `myapp://video` or let say i have also added `uber://` but when i open these from chrome browser, it takes me to google, it does not treat this as a link, So how will user reach to the content of this link, if its not opening from browser.

I tried this, but it opened the Google search, and not take me to the play store.

Kindly guide me how a user can use deep link? and reach to the app by using deep link.

[image]

**Manifest**

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="video/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: have you added same host and Schema like your URL open in browser.

Comment: deep linking is not working for some of android devices Eg: samsung J5 and Samsung J7. link is is opening in the default browser.

Comment: [Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) about deep linking.

Comment: Hey are you looking for app link or deep link ?  They look and sound almost similar but they serve a slightly different purpose.

Comment: deffered deep link, user click on link and it take it to particular activity

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Chrome does not treat URI schemes entered into the address bar as active links. You need to put it inside an `<a>` element.

Note that while this will work, *it is not a valid deep linking solution*. You should investigate Chrome Intents, or a full deep linking system like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links.

Comment: Hi Alex, do you know if React Navigation's Deep Linking solution works?

Comment: @AlejandroJS they do very different things. You're asking about a tool for routing within a React Native app. This question was about launching an app from the web browser.

Comment: @AlexBauer: Not sure if I get the idea correctly. I'm pasting `<a>uber://</a>` into chrome's address bar but the browser still treat it as keyword searching?

Comment: It needs to be an <a> tag in an actual page — not something you paste directly into the address bar.

Answer (score 23):

A quick solution is to just go to an HTML editor online, like for example this one:
https://htmledit.squarefree.com/

And paste your link over there. Something like:

```
<a href="fb://mygroup">My Facebook Group</a>
```

The editor will create the link for you and you'll be able to tap it and use the deeplink from your mobile device.

Answer (score 12):

Simply Just execute this command to your android studio terminal

```
adb shell am start -d deeplink
```

Example:

```
adb shell am start -d rm://settingpage/v1
```

Answer (score 10):

Opening deep link in smartphone.
[image]

1. Verify that you have installed the app belonged to deep link
2. Open website [Online Link Creator](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/html-link-code.html) in smartphone browser (i.e. Chrome)
3. Enter any text for link then paste the deep link into link input box.
4. Click on **Generate Link** button
5. Now you can see link just below button
6. Now you can click on that link. It will be open in desired App.
7. Done...!

Moreover, this process generates html & CSS code, which can be usable in WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like your app is not configured correctly.

To test deep links instead of browser you can use ADB: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html (look at the Test deep links section)

```
$ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d <URI> <PACKAGE>
```

If everything will be OK, then it might be some issue with browser.

To configure you app to handle deep links, please read this: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

If you want more information, please, post your configuration from AndroidManifest.xml: how you handle deep links.

Comment: Thanks, i have tested the app from adb its working fine, but from chrome browser its not working. The `uber://` is also not working

Comment: I have also edited my question, Its working from `Deep Link testing app`, but how can i give it to client when its not working from chrome

Comment: @Kirmani88 any update on this? were you able to get it working from browser?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox browser worked for me. I believe it handles private URI schemes

Answer (score 0):

While `<a />` tags are essential for deep linking in browsers, there's more to consider for robust app linking. Although Branch.io offers a solution, it has limitations like potential spam flagging and high costs for heavy usage. A more cost-effective and reliable approach involves using the `intent://` protocol and Google Play Store links. The `intent://` protocol (`intent://open?#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=com.example.app;end`) attempts to open your app, falling back to the Play Store if unsuccessful.

For the majority of cases, the Play Store link (`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app`) is sufficient, but `intent://` is invaluable for edge cases.

Additionally, implementing [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) ensures direct app opening for a seamless user experience.