# React Native Android Firebase Dynamic Link Not Working Well

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

I got an issue related to Firebase Dynamic Link.

I used the dynamic link and past it to the browser.

It just opens the play store in the browser instead of opening the Google Play application if I haven't installed it yet and seems the app is installed.

This is my link: https://deskimo.page.link/app

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                        android:host="deskimo.page.link"
                        android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                        android:host="deskimo.page.link"
                        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

The issue has just happened on Android device recently. I integrated Firebase Dynamic Link two years ago. This link still works well for IOS.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue is not with your code but it is something wrong where you are trying . I tried to copy paste your link to default browser and it is working fine .. it was redirecting to google playstore app not within browser .. but same i tried in google chrome by paste and go same link , google playstore open in browser itself instead of redirecting to google playstore app . It is strange but faced this and searched about it to know more and found this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287564/5696047

You can check deep link functionality except google chrome by just paste that link and send in messaging app and tap on that link